# Proportional version of the OCR-A font

Tags: fonts, typography, font-recommendation, monospace

I'm experimenting with the text for a logo and love the retro/computer/digital style of OCR-A. The only problem is that it is a monospaced font, and so sometimes the gap between the letters looks too large.

I'm trying to look for a proportional version of the same/similar font (ideally, free). kind of words can I use to describe this font and similar ones when searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automate by T26 comes to mind: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/automate/